# Given $\varphi \triangleq C_1\wedge\ldots \wedge C_m\in CNF$, $z_F$ or $z_T$ satisfies at least half of the $C_i$'s

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I saw the following statmant:

> Given $\varphi \triangleq C_1\wedge\ldots \wedge C_m\in CNF$, $z_F$ or $z_T$ satisfies at least half of the $C_i$'s.

Where $z_T$ works like so:
$$
\forall i,\,z_T(x_i)=T
$$
and $z_F$ works like so:
$$
\forall i,\,z_F(x_i)=F
$$
It does not make sense. I think it's wrong. Is it?

Comment: Take $C_i = x_i$, then $z_F$ does not satisfy any of $C_i$ obviously. Maybe some conditions?